# Using string template like eval

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm working with react/redux stack, and I have a section with dynamic state.
I have this structure

```
state:{formvalues:{email1:'',confirmEmail1:'',email2:'',confirmEmail2:'', etc }}
```

with dynamic emails,
I need to check if email1 is equal confirmEmail1 and the same thing for every mail.

I have found a solution with eval

```
v = `props.formValues.email${e} !== props.formValues.email${e}`;
eval(v);
```

And it work, but I cannot use the eval
I tried to use the template string in some differents way, but I have not found the solution,
I really hope that someone could help me,

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: `props.formValues['email' + e] !== props.formValues['confirmEmail' + e]`

Comment: It's working, thank you very much, you have saved my life